# Transform/Translate Flutter widget to negative 50% of it's width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Assume we have an empty parent widget (a Container), with no size, and positioned absolutely (within it's own parent) at a top/left (x/y) coordinate. Then we place a child widget (with variable size, which is not known beforehand) within the parent. Is there a way to position the child at -50% of its own width, such that the child's horizontal center appears at the x coordinate of its parent? I don't want to use global keys as there will be hundreds of instances. I've tried Transform.translate (only accepts a known x offset), FractionalOffsets, FractionallySizedBoxes, Alignments etc, but nothing seems to do what I'm trying to achieve. Does anyone know of a solution?

Edit: image demonstrating the objective
[image]

Comment: Can you put a picture of what you want?

Comment: @Mobina I've updated my question

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionalTranslation-class.html

Comment: @pskink that's exactly what I was looking for. If you care to make it into an answer I'll happily accept.

Comment: great, feel free to post a self answer then

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As per @pskink's comment, I was able to achieve this by combining a [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) and a [FractionalTranslation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionalTranslation-class.html)

```
Positioned(
    left: childWidget.x,
    top: childWidget.y,
    child: FractionalTranslation(
        translation: Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
        child: childWidget,
    )
);
```

Comment: In my case, the child is a Button, which cannot be pressed if e.g. the translation is smaller than -1.0. `transformHitTests` does not work. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @MarwinLebensky maybe wrap the button in a Container widget, and apply the translation to the container?

Comment: It simply will not work. I just found out that the flutter devs do not think that this is a bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6606
This poses many more problems than I expected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `AlignPositioned` widget from [align_positioned](https://pub.dev/packages/align_positioned) package.

```
AlignPositioned(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  moveByChildWidth: -0.5,          //negative 50% of child width
  child: Icon(
    Icons.info,
    size: 200,
  ),
),
```

*Edit:*

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(100, 200),
          child: Container(
            child: AlignPositioned(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              moveByChildWidth: -0.5,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.info,
                size: 100,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Gives the same result without the `Container` too i.e. making `Transform.translate` itself as the parent.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I've actually tried that package, but as far as I can tell, it won't work, because it requires the parent to have a defined size (which in my case it does not). It gives me an error: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderAlignPositionedBox#7e614 relayoutBoundary=up10

Comment: I tried out your case. It did not require the parent to have a defined size. And was able to position the parent using `Transform.translate` without a size. I'll edit the answer to include this part.

Comment: Actually I managed to get it working by removing the parent container entirely, and specifying the dx and dy properties of AlignPositioned directly (in conjunction with moveByChildWidth). Thanks for your answer, it gets my upvote, but @pskink's comment actually solves my problem more elegantly, and without the need for an external library.